# C# Deserializing JSON

Tags: c#

I am calling an API via C# which returns data in JSON format.  I am able to deserialize it correctly, using the ahs variable.  As I step through the code I see that the ahs variable is working correctly and it is being deserialzied.  The issue is as soon as I exit PreExecute the ahs variable becomes NULL, so I cannot use it after that.  Any ideas?

```
private AHS ahs;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();

        /*
         *  This method is calling an AHS API endpoint with  bearer token.   

           
            

        */

        string dataUrl = Variables.AHSEndpoint;
        string authToken = Variables.AuthenticationToken;
        string StartDate = Variables.StartDate;
        string EndDate = Variables.EndDate;
        string DivisionCode = Variables.DivisionCode;

        bool exceptionCancel = false;

        dataUrl = dataUrl + "/" + StartDate + "/" + EndDate + "/" + DivisionCode;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(dataUrl)
        };

      
       
        try
        { 
  
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(dataUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("request is not a http request");
            }

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
            request.ContinueTimeout = 120000;

            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string json;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream))
            {
                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }

           IEnumerable<AHS> ahs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AHS>>(json);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ComponentMetaData.FireError(10, "Get AHS Data", "An error occurred getting or de-searializing the web response.  " + e.Message, "", 0, out exceptionCancel);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two different variables called `ahs`.  One is a class-level field:

```
private AHS ahs;
```

Nothing ever uses this.  The other is a local variable:

```
IEnumerable<AHS> ahs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AHS>>(json);
```

This is assigned a value at the end of the method and then nothing ever uses that value.

It sounds like you wanted to assign to the class-level field, not a local variable:

```
ahs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AHS>>(json);
```

---

**Additionally...** These variables are different types.  One is a single instance of `AHS`, the other is a collection of `AHS` instances.  If what you're deserializing is a collection, make the variable that type:

```
private IEnumerable<AHS> ahs;
```

Comment: Thanks, David.  I have updated my variable to `private IEnumerable<AHS> ahs;` , since I am deserializing a collection. I have the class defined as `public class AHS` and am referencing the fields within the class as `ahs.field1`.  However, I am now getting an error saying: "IEnumerable<ScriptMain.AHS> does not contain a definition for field1.  Do I need to declare the class differently or reference the fields differently?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AndyMN: You're misunderstanding the difference between an object and a collection of objects.  To put it simply, a basket of apples is not an apple.  Since `ahs` is a *collection* of `AHS` objects, when you want to use `field1` then *which object* in that collection are you referring to?  You'd have to determine that.

Comment: Thanks, David.  I was able to figure it out.  I'm a non C# guy being asked to do C# work.  Again, I appreciate the help.